# Array of structures of function pointers C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I'm trying to initialize an array of structures containing pointer on function :

```
typedef struct struct_actioncommand {
    char *action;
    void (*command)(my_type);
} type_actioncommand;
```

To initialize each pointer with its function name I'm using this method :

```
static const type_actioncommand g_cmd_tab[] = {
    {"Action1", function1},
    {"Action2", function2},
    {"Action3", function3},
    {NULL, NULL}
};
```

But it doesn't work. 
When I try to compile with "gcc", I have the following message:

> myfile.c:16:3: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
>     {"Action1", function1},
>     ^
>   myfile.c:16:3: error: (near initialization for g_cmd_tab[0].command) [-Werror]
>   myfile.c:17:3: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
>     {"Action2", function2},
>     ^
>   myfile.c:17:3: error: (near initialization for g_cmd_tab[1].command) [-Werror]
>   myfile.c:18:3: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
>     {"Action3", function3},
>     ^
>   myfile.c:18:3: error: (near initialization for g_cmd_tab[2].command) [-Werror]
>   cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

each function is defined according to this prototype :

```
void function1(my_type *var1);
```

I'm a little bit confuse now since I dont see how to fix my problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us `function1` etc.? Or at least their prototypes (declarations)? Though we would prefer a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What are the definitions of `function1`, `function2`, and `function3`?

Comment: Also, those errors looks like they come from GCC, which is usually very good with informational notes like what was expected and what was given. Did you copy-paste the *full* output, including such informational notes?

Comment: In the structure, the argument to `command` is a `my_type` *object*, but the declaration you show for `function1` shows the argument being a *pointer* to `my_type`. Different, and incompatible, types.

Comment: @Roulians do you read the code you paste? stars matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your struct, the `command` member:

```
void (*command)(my_type);
```

Has type "pointer to function which take a parameter of type `my_type` and returns `void`.

Your function:

```
void function1(my_type *var1);
```

Has type "function which takes a parameter of  type `my_type *` and returns `void`.

The parameters of the function pointer don't match the parameters of the functions you assign to them.  That makes the pointers incompatible.

To fix this, change the type of the function pointer to match the functions that are assigned to it:

```
void (*command)(my_type *);
```